# Is SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue injection safe?

Tags: .net, parameters, sql-injection, sqlcommand, prepared-statement

Is the `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue` method injection-safe?

It accepts an `Object` for the payload, so how could it protect against injection?

Answer (score 7):

It actually depends on how you use them.

See the difference here. First one is secure but not the second one.

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = "select * from Books where Title = @title";
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", txtTitle.Text);
```

---

```
string sql = "select * from Books where title = " + txtTitle.Text;
sqlCommand.CommandText = "exec(@sql)";
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("sql", sql);
```

---

See more details about it at [Does asp.net protect against sql injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144566/does-asp-net-protect-against-sql-injection-attacks)