# Passing value of textbox to a class VS2013 ASPX C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a Gridview.aspx, Gridview.aspx.cs and GetData.cs (class)

In Gridview.aspx I have a textbox named **SearchData** and a button named **SearchBtn**

I have this in my Gridview.aspx.cs >>>

```
protected void SearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (!IsPostBack){
        Search_Grid();
    }
}

void Search_Grid(){ 
    DataGridView.DataSource = obj.Search_Data();
    DataGridView.DataBind();
}
```

And since it's my first time to use a class, here's what i put in GetData.cs >>>

```
public DataTable Search_Data(){
    adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from MyTable " +
                                      "where MyID = '" + 
                                       value_of_my_SearchData_textbox + 
                                       "'", con);
    dt = new DataTable();
    adap.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

**ASPX Code**
GridView.aspx code is long, but here's what under the gridview part:

```
<table id="TBL_GridView" runat="server" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td  text-align:center">*** TEST ONLY ***</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >  
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Procedure name: "></asp:Label> &nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="SearchData" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="SearchBtn" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="SearchBtn_Click" /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td >
            <asp:GridView ID="DataGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" 
                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="281px" style="margin-top: 0px" Width="1000px" 
                OnRowCancelingEdit="DataGridView_RowCancelingEdit"  
                OnRowEditing="DataGridView_RowEditing" HorizontalAlign="Center" >

                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />

                <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>Recipe Name</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="recpname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("recpname")%>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="recpname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="recpname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>Standard Time</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="stdtime" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("stdtime")%>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="stdtime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="stdtime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>Operation</HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="BtnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" Width="60px" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="BtnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" Width="60px" />
                            <asp:Button ID="BtnCancle" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" Width="60px" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="BtnInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert"  Width="60px" OnClick="BtnInsert_Click" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How should I pass the value of my textbox to my class?

Comment: Please add GridView (.aspx) code.

Comment: Hi @Sunil see below comment for the Gridview.aspx code

Comment: Edit the question and add there. Don't add as an answer.It will only get you down votes. I have added for you for now, so you can go ahead and delete your answer.

Comment: 1) `SearchBtn_Click` **is** a `Postback` 2) All the [things about sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5144566/304683)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that your text box SearchData is just an ordinary textbox outside of gridview and not in the gridview.

You can simply use:

```
SearchData.Text
```

Change the methods to pass `SearchData.Text`

```
protected void SearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (!IsPostBack){
        Search_Grid(SearchData.Text);
    }
}

void Search_Grid(string searchValue){ 
    DataGridView.DataSource = obj.Search_Data(searchValue);
    DataGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Finally use it:

```
public DataTable Search_Data(string searchValue){
   adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from MyTable " +
                                  "where MyID = '" + 
                                   searchValue + 
                                   "'", con);
   dt = new DataTable();
   adap.Fill(dt);
   return dt;
}
```

However, note this code is prone to **SQL Injection** attack because you are adding value inline, so an attacker can add `; delete from my table` to wipe your data.

You should parameterize your query.

```
adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from MyTable where MyID = @myIdValue", con);
```

Comment: Do I need to add something, it gives me the error : The name 'SearchData' does not exists in the current context

Comment: Updated. You need to pass SearchData.Text from the UI down to the method.

Comment: Thanks for that! How about the gridview? How do I refresh it? It doesn't show the data.

Comment: You don't need it `!IsPostBack` condition since it will always be a postback once the button is clicked

Comment: But the result is not reflecting on my gridview. So, I tried to test if button is working. On my Page_Load, I initially displayed my gridview, now I create a new button and just move my code from the Page_Load to MyButton_Click. Nothing display.

Comment: I get it now guys! Thanks for your help!